# How VPN server in some country accepts requests if it is behind NAT?

Tags: port-forwarding, openvpn

I use openVPN application and I download its openVPN config files from here: http://www.vpngate.net/en/  to connect with VPN server. Suppose the VPN server I'm trying to connect with is behind NAT so obviously if I send a request, it'll be blocked by Its NAT. VPN server has nowhere to know who wants to connect with it in this globe.
What topology VPN server is using to accept every VPN client's request from any IP address and port?
I assume that VPN server may be using "port forwarding" which is accepting every incoming request no matter from what IP address and port the request is coming.

Comment: Why do you think any of these servers are behind NAT?

Comment: OpenVPN and Softether VPN are open source projects. Their VPN community allow every user to create VPN servers for public internet users. If you visit that link I mentioned above you will find so many third-party VPN servers which are a part of openVPN programme and many of them are behind NAT. That's why they are somewhat slow.

Comment: I see no mention of NAT on that page at all, except on the “Join” page. NAT is also not related to speed.

Comment: @DanielB that page is not a reference for NAT. I was referring to third-party openVPN servers community. Some of them operate their VPN servers from behind the NAT because they are also internet users like us. I got my answer from Radial Apps about how they operate.

Comment: Daniel I thought you know about that link because it's a very famous community. You can see their "users per day" in their table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Suppose the VPN server I'm trying to connect with is behind NAT so
>   obviously if I send a request, it'll be blocked by Its NAT. VPN server
>   has nowhere to know who wants to connect with it in this globe.

Yes, if the VPN server is behind NAT, you won't be able to connect to it. The VPN Server actually opens up a port for others to connect and then people around the world connect to it. "Port Forwarding" means that suppose you have a firewall between the VPN Server and the internet (or say a router), then you define a forward so that every connection to a specific port on the router gets completely forwarded to the Server, as if the router didn't exist. As far as the topology is concerned, it's all about having (at least) one router connected to the internet for the server which can pass on requests to it. It could be anything (usually star in small setups). So the basic flow is as such:

Client PC --> Client router --> ISP --> Other routing accross the internet --> ISP of Server --> Router of Server --> Server

The reverse happens in the opposite direction. Finally, it is the IP of the Client router and the Router of the server that are used for all the routing. The last step is the one that involves port forwarding (actually there could be multiple machines running behind a single router running VPN on different ports too)

Comment: I've replaced the word protocol with topology.

Comment: The port VPN server has opened, does that port accept requests coming from any port?

Comment: Yes. Actually, large, random port numbers like 52000 etc are generally used.